# Express throws error before request is complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, http-get

I am attempting to query a database and return the result to express before a render the result onto a template. Currently, I am using Axios and it sends a request to `localhost:3000/api/endpoint`. I have verified that the endpoint works through postman and it returns what I want from MongoDB.

My web server code looks like this:

```
app.get('/post/:id', (req, res) => {

  axios.get(`localhost:3000/post/${req.params.id}`)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    res.render('post', { content: response.content });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.render('404', { error: err });
  });
});
```

For some reason, axios (or express) does not wait for the API to return the response, and instead jumps to the catch and returns the 404 page. I'm not sure why it behaves this way.

Note - the error that is returned is either: ECONNRESET or socket hang up

How can I fix it, so that express (or axios) waits for the API query to finish, before rendering it on the page?

Comment: Try to set up full url with http-protocol `http://localhost:3000/...` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000/...`

Comment: Can you confirm if request sent by express is received by the server?

Comment: Why are you trying to query database using Axios and not some database related npm module?

Comment: I'm querying my database with mongoose. I calling the API with Axios.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [dhilt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3211932/dhilt) for the answer. Changing `localhost` to `http://localhost` fixed the problem, and now it's working flawlessly.